# Is there a way I can access the user profile picture filename?

Tags: 7, views, users

I want to create a view in the Drupal 7, where I can show the User Profile picture name (the original which user uploaded) and the path its saved.

Comment: Sounds like a custom file field formatter. So that when you display the image choose a formatter like "URL to image" but then your own custom one like "Name of image".

Comment: Yes. if customer has uploaded the image with his name it should be displayed.

Comment: Yes, then try that.

Comment: I am a new bee with Drupal, so I didn't understand it to the full. Actually I check the DB, but no where the original picture name is getting saved.  you are saying to Create a custom field to save the original name ?